# Angular pass function arguments from directive to controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Im trying to implement directive pagination and i want to pass the number of the current page from the directive to a controller and then run a function from the controller with this argument but im getting undefined.

```
<account-pagination pagination-config="paginationConfig" on-change="pageChanged()">
</account-pagination>
```

controller:

```
$scope.pageChanged = function(page) {
    console.log(page); // undefined 
}
```

directive:

```
scope: {
      paginationConfig: '=',
      onChange: '&',
    }


$scope.moveToPage = function(numPage) {
    $scope.currentPage = numPage;
    getPaginData(numPage);
 }

function getPaginData(numPage) {
    $scope.onChange({page: numPage});
}
```

template directive:

```
<li ng-repeat="num in numPages"><a ng-click="moveToPage(num)" ng-class="{pageActive: isActive(num)}">{{num}}</a></li>
```

Comment: You are not passing the current page by parameter to your `on-change="pageChanged()"` tag. Does this have a reason?

Comment: yes that has to be because you are not passing the page in the event itself `on-change="pageChanged()"` here you are not passing any argument and you are using it in the function so it is undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK i find the solution:

```
<account-pagination pagination-config="paginationConfig" on-change="pageChanged">
</account-pagination>

scope: {
      paginationConfig: '=',
      onChange: '=',
    }

$scope.pageChanged = function(page) {
    console.log(page);
}

$scope.moveToPage = function(numPage) {
    $scope.currentPage = numPage;
    $scope.onChange(numPage);
 }
```

Comment: Glad you find the answer to your question, you needed then to pass your function by name and not calling it with `()`, good to know ;)